# why does Fuzzywuzzy python script take forever to generate results?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

To give an idea, I have an excel file(.xlsx format) within which I am working with 2 sheets at a time.

I am interested in 'entity name' from sheet a and 'name' from sheet b.

Sheet b has 'name' column written 7times.

my sheet a looks like this.

```
Isin    Entity Name
DE0005545503    1&1 AG
US68243Q1067    1-800-Flowers.Com Inc
US68269G1076    1Life Healthcare Inc
US3369011032    1st Source Corp
```

while my sheet b looks like this

```
name    company_id  name    company_id  name    company_id  name    company_id  name    company_id  name    company_id  name
LIVERPOOL PARTNERS MICROCAP GROWTH FUND MANAGER PTY LTD 586056  FERRARI NADIA   1000741 DORSET COMMUNITY RADIO LTD  1250023 Hunan Guangtongsheng Communication Service Co., Ltd.    1500335 Steffes PrÃ¼f- und Messtechnik GmbH,    1550006 CHL SRL 2000320 Qu Star, Inc.
BISCUIT AVENUE PTY LTD  586474  D AMBROSIO MARIA    1000382 LUCKY WORLD PRODUCTIONS LIMITED 1250024 Zhuzhou Wanlian Telecommunication Co., Ltd. 1500354 e42 II GmbH 1550510 EGGTRONIC SPA   2000023 Molly Shaheen, L.L.C.
CL MAY1212 PTY LTD  586475  TORIJA ZANE LUCIA LUCIA 1000389 FYLDE COAST MEDIA LTD   1250034 Zhongyi Tietong Co., Ltd. Yanling Xiayang Broadband TV Service Center   1500376 Valorem Capital UG (haftungsbeschrÃ¤nkt)    1550539 MARACAIBA INVEST SRL    2000139 Truptisudhir Pharmacy Inc
```

alternatively you can find the sheet b here:[image]

Here's my code

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz


filename = 'C:/Users/Downloads/SUniverse.xlsx'
dataframe1 = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='A')
dataframe2 = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='B')
# print(dataframe1.head())
# print(dataframe2.head())

# Clean customers lists
A_cleaned = [df1 for df1 in dataframe1["Entity Name"] if not(pd.isnull(df1))]
B_cleaned = [df2 for df2 in dataframe2["name"].unique() if not(pd.isnull(df2))]
print(A_cleaned)
print(B_cleaned)

# Perform fuzzy string matching
tuples_list = [max([(fuzz.token_set_ratio(i,j),j) for j in B_cleaned]) for i in A_cleaned]
print(tuples_list)

# Unpack list of tuples into two lists
similarity_score, fuzzy_match = map(list,zip(*tuples_list))
# Create pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"I_Entity_Name":A_cleaned, "I_Name": fuzzy_match, "similarity score":similarity_score})
df.to_excel("C:/Users/Downloads/fuz-match-output.xlsx", sheet_name="Fuzzy String Matching", index=False)
print('done!')
```

The code takes forever to generate results. It has been over 20hours and the script is still running. My excel input file is going over 50mbs in size(just wanna say that it contains millions of records).

How do I ensure that my script runs at a faster pace and generates the result? I want the output to be this:

```
Entity Name     Name       fuzzy score
apple          APPLE        100
.
.
.
```

Comment: `sheet b` is ambiguous, can you re format it ?

Comment: @Timeless I've edited my question and added a screengrab of sheet, hope that helps.